# how to read string upto certain comma with java

Tags: java, string, file

i need to read a file upto certain comma,for example;
`String s=hii,lol,wow,and,finally`

need output as `hii,lol,wow,and` 
Dont want last comma followed with characters 
As my code is reading last comma string 
Example:iam getting my code out put as: `finally`
Below is my code
please guide me

```
File file =new File("C:/Users/xyz.txt");

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

String filke = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

String[] pieces = filke.split("(?=,)");

String answer = Arrays.stream(pieces).skip(pieces.length - 1).collect(Collectors.joining());

String www=answer.substring(1);

System.out.format("Answer = \"%s\"%n", www);
```

Comment: With your rep. you should know [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) questions..

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Why not remove the last `,` +++

Comment: Some substring and lastIndexOf is probably what you need

Comment: So use split() as you do, and ignore the last element.

Comment: @String hi could you consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use regex for this. Just get the index of the last `','` and get the substring from `0` to that index:

```
String answer = "hii,lol,wow,and,finally";
String www = answer.substring(0, answer.lastIndexOf(','));
System.out.println(www); // prints hii,lol,wow,and
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` in Java has a method called `lastIndexOf(String str)`. That might come in handy for you.
Say your input is `String s = "hii,lol,wow,and,finally";`
You can do a `String` operation like:

```
String s = "hii,lol,wow,and,finally";
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(","));
```

This gives you the output: `hii,lol,wow,and`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use java 8 stream to do it for you maybe try filter ?

```
String answer = Arrays.stream(pieces).filter(p -> !Objects.equals(p, pieces[pieces.length-1])).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

this will print `Answer = "hii,lol,wow,and"`

Answer (score 0):

To have stricly regex you can use the `Pattern.compile` and `Matcher`

```
Pattern.compile("\w+(?=,)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filke);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ","); // regex not good enough, maybe someone can edit it to include , (comma)
}
```

Will match `hii, lol, wow, and,`
See the regex example here https://regex101.com/r/1iZDjg/1